# Use csv.reader to read a file into a list but skip a specific column (Python)

Tags: python

Hello and thanks in advance for any help.  I am new to Python and I've found and tried many solutions but I can't seem to get the correct output.

I have a csv file with several columns. I want to skip the field names/first row and then read the file into a list.  I also want to skip a column resulting in something like: column 1, column 2, column 3, column 5...  I want do this because I am merging two other csv files (that are converted to lists) and they have different structures.

Here's my original code before I discovered the csv files had different structures...

```
#convert input file1 to list
reader = csv.reader(file1,delimiter=',')
next(reader)    
list_1 = []
list_1 = list(reader)
```

I have tried:

```
reader = csv.reader(file1,delimiter=',')
next(reader)
included_cols = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]

for row in reader:
    content = list(row[i] for i in included_cols)

list_1 = list(content)
```

But this doesn't output correctly down the line when I merge the three lists into a sorted list like so:

```
unsortedList = list_1 + list_2 + list_3
```

and then I create a sorted list:

```
sortedList = sorted(unsortedList,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

and try to output the file like this:

```
with open('output.csv','a') as result_file:
    wr = csv.writer(result_file, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerows(sortedList)
```

The resulting output:
[weird at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO8rn.jpg)

Comment: Set "list_1" to an empty list and "append" each list in "content" to "list_1" in the for-loop. So you get a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would use pandas instead. Say you have the CSV file called `test.csv`:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

We can read it using pandas:

```py
import itertools
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=[0], usecols=[0,1,3], header=None)
print(df)
   0  1  3
0  1  2  4
1  5  6  8
```

Then, you can generate the lists from rows as:

```
lists = df.values.tolist()
```

And finally into a single list:

```
merged = list(itertools.chain(*lists))
print(merged)
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```